# A question about the expression "shame on me"

Tags: phrase-usage

I know there are lots of examples where you can find "shame on me", including a proverb. However, I remember how a few teachers (not only ESL teachers from my country but also the native speakers) mentioned that one can say "shame on you" but not "shame on me". I even remember the phrase "shame works with you but not with me".
So, my question is: is it appropriate to say "shame on me"?
Thank you for your answer in advanced.

Comment: Normally you'd say "shame on you" to someone else, but there's absolutely no reason you can't turn it on yourself if you feel you've done something wrong. "Oh, if I did that by mistake, then shame on me."

Comment: "Fool me once, shame on you.  Fool me twice, shame on me!" - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fool_me_once,_shame_on_you;_fool_me_twice,_shame_on_me

Comment: ***Unless*** you're quoting or alluding to the "once / twice" saying, it's ***never*** appropriate to say ***Shame on me*** as an exclamation / admission that one has behaved badly. I can't make any sense of @ralph.m's example. You shouldn't need to castigate yourself so thoroughly for a *mistake* (there's a difference between shame and embarrassment).

Comment: "Shame on me" is not usually used with seriousness.  It frequently expresses hyperbole, used in situations where someone else is overly upset about one's minor misstep or mistake, as in "Shame on me for trying to help!", or when the same (minor) error is made multiple times.  From a web source, a restaurant review: "Shame on me for trying this place 4 times. The food is awful."

Answer (score 0):

It is rarely appropriate to say "shame on me," because this is an awkward thing to say. It's like you are telling other people to shame you. However, it is perfectly grammatically correct.

This could be used in two scenarios. First, an extremely dramatic, probably fictional scene in a book or movie where a character is extremely distressed about a perceived improper action and wants to take responsibility or be punished for it in some way. Second, and this is how you'd probably actually see it used in reality, is the usage that Meg described. That is, you could use it humorously for something that clearly doesn't warrant literal shame. The humor is from the fact that "shame on me" carries substantial weight if used seriously, but you are using it very lightly for something which is not so serious, like trying a bad restaurant too many times or eating a cookie when dieting.